# Sampling from a high dimensional function

Tags: function, machine-learning, statistics, sampling

I have a function `f` that takes `N` real-valued inputs and is very expensive to compute. Each of the `N` inputs, call one by `n`, has a range of values `(n_min, n_max)` that it can take on. I am interested in studying the properties of `f` by generating samples on various inputs and seeing what outputs it produces. (The goal is to use ML to build an approximator for `f`.)

Let's say that due to time constraints I can only generate 1000 samples. Is it "better" to select the set of `N`s that I feed to `f` by

(A) iterating from `n_min` to `n_max` with a big enough step size for each `n`, or

(B) uniformly sampling each `n` on the range of `(n_min, n_max)`?

Choice (A) has the desirable property of keeping every other input fixed while varying only one value at a time, but choice (B) has the desirable property of likely exploring more parts of the input space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**B** is better when the function does not have equal variance over all the inputs, which it probably does not. In the extreme case, imagine you have 1000 samples, 3 inputs, but only one of them actually affects the function. If you sample over a 10x10x10 regular grid, as in **A**, you will end up with only 10 samples of the relevant input. If you sample with a uniform distribution, all 1000 samples will be informative.

As a variation on **B**, consider using a quasi-random sequence of inputs, such as the [Sobol sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence). The advantage over a uniform distribution is that your input space coverage won't have clusters or holes.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks. I'm looking for means of generating Sobol sequences in Python but I'm coming up a bit short.

Comment: There is a C++ implementation that I use. I don't know how easy it would be to reproduce in Python. http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~fkuo/sobol/